# Проверить отсутствие повторяющихся символов

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Помогите составить ругулярку для проверки в строке одинаковых символов.

Например: `abaa@mail.ru` `ttg.tu` если подряд идет 2 или более символов то это **FALSE**

Вот, что я делал

```js
var antiFlood = function(str) {
      var pattern = new RegExp(~(.)\\1{2}~);
      return pattern.test(str);
    }
```

Comment: Ваша регулярка проверяет на три одинаковых символа. Не забывайте что то что в скобках тоже учитывается. Только уберите один слеш - он лишний

Answer (score 2):

К чему такие сложности воротить..

```js
const antiFlood= text => /(.)\1/.test(text);
console.log(antiFlood('abc'));
console.log(antiFlood('abbc'));
```

Comment: а как поправить регулярку, чтобы фукция работала когда более 2х символов одинаковых?

antiFlood= text => /(.)\2/.test(text); - не работает

Comment: Сделал так - /(.)\1{2}/

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log( !/(.)\1{1,}/g.test("James") )
console.log( !/(.)\1{1,}/g.test("Jamees") )
```